# How to get class name in reacjs?

Tags: reactjs

How we can retrieve class elements in reactjs

I have used below javascript code to get the class elements but. Is there any possibilities to get in reactjs.

```
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('control-m');
```

Comment: you can use ref 
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `useRef` hook this way:

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
const sample = () =>{
   const elementRef = useRef(null);
   // this is equivalent of componentDidMount
   useEffect(()=>console.log(elementRef.current), [])
   return <div className="control-m" ref={elementRed}></div>
}
```

But to be honest, you need to read react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). It's impossible to select items with classNames in react and you shouldn't mutate DOM. React doesn't work as you think according to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
let elements = document.getElementById('control-m');
console.log('ClassName', elements.className); 

return(
<div id='control-m' className='header' />
)
```

Another way is you can use `ref` https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

Comment: this.rdlRef = React.createRef();